# How to access the keys and values of dictionary passed as argument in method

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a c# background and I am trying to pass a dictionary in method and some some I want to check if a specific key exists or not. If that key exists in dictionary and then I want to perform few other things.

Let suppose if have following dictionary:

```
tel = {'jack': 4098, 'sape': 4139}
```

and I want to check whether key 'sape' exists or not? In method somehow, I do not know the type of argument. How can I cast to dictionary in order to  retrieve keys and values.

In method I want to check:

```
keys = tel.keys () ;
keys.__contains__('sap')
do something
```

However, in method, I do not have information about the type of passed argument.

Comment: What do you mean by 'cast to a dictionary'? If your function requires a dictionary, then just assume it *is* a dictionary and use `if 'sap' in tel:`.

Comment: You should not use `__magic_methods__` directly here, nor call `.keys()`. Just use the `in` operator directly on the `tel` dictionary.

Comment: As I mentioned that I am pretty new in python and could not find this kind of details.

Comment: Python uses duck typing, different to C#.

Comment: I was going to recommend the Python tutorial, but you're probably already reading that -- that's where that example [comes from](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) originally.  It gives "'guido' in tel" as an example membership test, and says " To check whether a single key is in the dictionary, use the `in` keyword."

Comment: @User1551892: then read through the [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/) some more; it does cover details like these, including [membership testing in dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries). Then again, it looks like you already are, as your example comes straight from that section.

Comment: Thanks for you explanation. I was trying to follow usual c# approaches to fix this issue and I was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Few things to note about Python:

Python is not statically typed like C#. The function/method signature doesn't contain the data types of the parameters. So you do not need to cast the passed in value to a dictionary. Instead you assume that what is passed in is a dictionary and work on it. If you expect that something other than dictionary will be passed you can either use [exception handling](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html) to catch any issues or you can use [isinstance](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance) to check what is passed in is what you expect. Having said that casting does exist in python; for example you can convert an int 1 to a string by str(1).

Also note that if use the `in` keyword it will work for any iterable not just dictionary.

Example:

```
>>> 'jack' in 'lumberjack'
True
>>> tel = {'jack': 4098, 'sape': 4139}
>>> 'jack' in tel
True
>>>
```

If you really want to check if something is a dictionary you can do like this:

```
>>> isinstance(tel,dict)
True
```